# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20999: Invalid combination of paramters passed to procedure

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a requirement where i have to handle optional parameters of procedure. I am able to execute it successfully by following

[Invoking procedure defaults without binding values to parameters in Jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433850/invoking-procedure-defaults-without-binding-values-to-parameters-in-jdbc).

It works fine when i have all the parameters to procedure is IN parameter i.e., no registerOutParameter. if I am having OUT parameters and handling it, it is giving me error as below.

My current code

```
String getDBUSERCursorSql = "{call greetings (param_4 => ?,param_5 => ?, param_6 => ? , param_7 => ? )}";

    Connection dbConnection = dataSource.getConnection();
    callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(getDBUSERCursorSql);
    callableStatement.setString(1, "paramFoure");
    callableStatement.setString(2,"paramSix");
    callableStatement.setString(3,"paramSeven");
    callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    callableStatement.execute();
```

Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20999: Invalid combination of paramters passed to procedure
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.GREETINGS", line 846
ORA-06512: at line 1

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:204)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1007)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.executeUpdate(OracleCallableStatement.java:4739)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
```

Comment: The error is being reported at line 846 of your procedure, so you need to look there rather than at how you're calling it. Also, don't create you own objects in the `system` schema, create your own user and work with that instead.

Comment: @AlexPoole: Thanks. The error occurs due to exception is thrown inside procedure